# Allowing serial port access in sandboxed Swift MacOS app

Tags: swift, macos, serial-port, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

I have an in Swift that uses the ORSSerialPort library to access a serial port (a USB device of our own design).  I am now trying to distribute it, but in order to do that on the require the app to be Sandboxed.  However when I sandbox access to the serial port is blocked ('Operation not permitted.').
How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you add the [com.apple.security.device.usb](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-the-macos-app-sandbox) entitlement?

Comment: I did.  I still get the "Serial port....Code=1 "Operation not permitted".... error.